# convert from floatbuffer to byte[]

Tags: java, floatbuffer

I'm trying to find a way to use jack-audio in java. I've managed to create wrapper based on jnajack to get audio from jacks' port to java app (the original jnajack is not working with jack 1.9.8), but I can't find a way to manipulate data. I'm gettin' a `List<FloatBuffer>`, and for further data manipulation I need to convert it to `byte[]`.

To put put it simple... firstly I want to save data to a file, but java sound api as I understand can only save data from `TargetDataLine` and/or `byte[]`. How can I convert `FloatBuffer` to `byte[]`? The only way I can find is `floatbuffer.get(float[])` and somehow (don't know how) convert `float[]` to `byte[]`.

Comment: What is the exact name of the class of 'floatbuffer'?

Answer (score 7):

> How can I convert `FloatBuffer` to `byte[]`?

```
FloatBuffer floatbuffer;

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(floatbuffer.capacity() * 4);
byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put(floatbuffer);
byte[] bytearray = byteBuffer.array();
```

You may have to change the [byte order](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order%28java.nio.ByteOrder%29).

Answer (score 1):

So jnajack uses a different representation of the audio data than the standard java sound api functions.

I don't see it in jnajack's specs, but I imagine it represents the audio as floats between -1 and 1.

I'm not too familiar with the Java Sound API, but I could imagine it uses bytes ranged between -128 and 127.

In other words, you'd have to convert between the two by multiplying by 128.

I'd say the neat way to do this would be `byte converted = Float.valueOf(original * 128).byteValue()`. If needed it's probably possible to do this with only primitives, which should be faster.

Comment: it's not  jnajack uses a different representation of the audio data! jnajack(as jjack too) is simply a JNA/JNI for Jack Audio Tool. the problem.

Comment: `Float.valueOf(original * 128).byteValue()` is exactly the same as `(byte)(original * 128)`. However, the value `1.0` will wrap to `-128`.