# Convert FloatBuffer[] to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, byte, floatbuffer

I've been searching for a way to convert a FloatBuffer array to  a byte array. I have found a way to convert a FloatBuffer object to byte[]:
[convert from floatbuffer to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298997/convert-from-floatbuffer-to-byte)

But after searching the Internet for several hours I haven't been able to find something equivalent to convert from FloatBuffer[].

And to do the inverse, to convert from byte[] to FloatBuffer[], I've only found this:

`ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

   oos.writeObject(floatBufferObject);

   byte [] descriptorsBytes = bos.toByteArray();`

But it seems a little strange there is not a simpler way to do this.
Maybe I'm missing something very obvious, maybe I should convert the FloatBuffer array to other type that is simpler to convert to a byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already had the answer on how to convert one `FloatBuffer` into a byte array, so simply extend that to convert an array of them:

```
final FloatBuffer[] floatBuffers = new FloatBuffer[] {...};
final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(sumOfFloatBufferCapacities) * 4);
final FloatBuffer floatBufView = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
for (final FloatBuffer fBuf : floatBuffers) {
    floatBufView.put(fBuf);
}
byte[] data = byteBuffer.array();
```

The above is pseudocode, you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now I'm trying to convert the byte array back to FloatBuffer[] doing something like this: FloatBuffer fb = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).asFloatBuffer();  But this retrieves the array as just one row. Is there a way to get it as FloatBuffer[] or I have to do another for to divide it in diferent rows...?

Comment: @MarciaGarcia - Once you merge the arrays there is no way of determining which floats should go where, unless you keep track externally (say in a list of integers), of the number of floats that should go into each FloatBuffer.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want *one* `FloatBuffer`, or multiple?

To convert from a `FloatBuffer` to a `byte[]`, you could do something like

```
 FloatBuffer input;
 byte[] output = new byte[input.capacity() * 4];
 ByteBuffer.wrap(output).asFloatBuffer().put(input);
```

The other direction would just be

```
 ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).asFloatBuffer()
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have a simple FloatBuffer, I have an array of FloatBuffer objects. This "FloatBuffer[]" object doesn't have methods like "get", "put", "wrap". Only each row of the FloatBuffer Array, that can be accessed as floatBufferArray[i] has those methods avaible.

Comment: Then you'll have to do it one at a time, but these implementations should give you an idea as to how to convert each row between `FloatBuffer` and bytes.

Comment: But, because I need the byte array to store this info in a database, I have to store this as just one byte array, not one for each FloatBuffer row of the FloatBuffer array. So if I do it one FloatBuffer at a time, I'll have multiple byte arrays...

Comment: Create one big `ByteBuffer`, call its `asFloatBuffer()` method, and then put each of the small `FloatBuffer`s into that big `FloatBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The conversion in the other direction works too, with ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).asFloatBuffer(); but I obtain the result as just a FloatBuffer, not a FloatBuffer array. Is there a way to obtain each of the original FloatBuffer rows separated?

Answer (score 0):

Convert FloatBuffer[] to byte[]:

```
    FloatBuffer[] buffers = ...
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (FloatBuffer fb : buffers) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(fb.capacity() * 4);
        byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer().put(fb);
        bos.write(byteBuffer.array());
    }
    byte[] ba = bos.toByteArray();
```